# Unobtrusive Fast-filter Dropdown <optgroup> implementaion

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using UFD Autocomplete plugin, Can anyone suggest how to implement the OPTGROUP feature in this plugin?

thanks.

Comment: What plugin? Does it have documentation?

Comment: Its an autocomplete plugin the project home page is [here](http://code.google.com/p/ufd/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Features](http://code.google.com/p/ufd/wiki/Features) page...

> **Limitations**
>
> Sounds great, but what about the missing features that you might want to know about for your situation:
>
> - ***no `<OPTGROUP ..>` support.*** Possible to implement.
> - no complex per-item content, such as multiple images or HTML. A single block `<LI .. >` with background image, hover/active class and CSS is all you get - performance is more important sorry.
> - no support for multiple selection, i.e. `<SELECT multiple .. >`. (thetoolman) doesn't recommend them as a good UI widget: ctrl + click for form entry? no thanks. Use checkboxes or some better metaphor!
> - no JSON/ajax/ajax-autocomplete support. This is just a wrapper on a `<SELECT.. >` tag, so you can modify or inject new `<OPTION ..>`s to the master via any technique/tool you prefer, then simply trigger a reload from that master `<SELECT ..>` :)
> - limited backwards compatibility with sexy-combo configuration, CSS, callbacks etc. if you are upgrading. The transition should be easy however, as the included skins use the same file layout more or less.
> - many events are not passed on, such as key events. Welcome use-case suggestions for event mimicing of other types.
> - Not yet tested with screen-readers and other special access techniques. Gladly accept suggestions, especially with the dummy ARIA-enabled themeroller test in the current demo page linked above.

If you're asking how to implement it yourself, you'll need to start on it and ask a question when you get stuck.